# chrome android url navbar not sliding up on scroll

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, polymer, navbar

I noticed that with core animated pages+ toolbar, at least on android 5.0/chrome, when we scroll down a page, the url navbar doesn't slide up as it should.

for instance, in the following page, the url bar never slides up.

https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#core-toolbar

is there any way to have the url navbar working as expected?

best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the expected behavior. we can hack it in JS but might not be worth it.